# Differential operators in QM whose domain is a subspace of $L^2$ act on equivalence classes - How is that even defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, differentiation

As far as I know, differential operators in Quantum Mechanics (for example the momentum operator) are defined on a subspace of $L^2$ (if $L^2$ is the Hilbert space). This means that they act on equivalence classes - for what subspace and how is the derivative defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each equivalence class in the domain must contain a differentiable element. The differential operator acts on those representatives. Notice that each such representative is necessarily unique, since two continuous functions which are different on a zero measure set are actually everywhere  equal. So the action is well defined.